# SVG rendering in Java using SWT - Batik too slow

Tags: java, vector, svg, swt, batik

I am having performance issues with Batik when I try to render SVG files using SWT. It seems like a very bloated library but the only other one I could find was SVGSalamander and it looks like it's Swing only. Is there a way to render the SVGs without converting them to a bitmap form first that's faster? It needs to be cross platform.

Comment: I started out trying to find an SVG rendering solution for my Java app and ended up using Batik's PNGTranscoder. It requires a bit more up front work but it worked out better for me to just render all the SVGs to PNGs as soon as I knew what size I needed everything to be. I know that's not what you want but I think the savings in re-rendering time (especially for complicated SVGs) is significant I think. This won't help of course if you want to manipulate the SVG elements in real-time. If you like, I can post a code snippet. I took me quite some time to figure it all out :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need rendering, I highly recommend using Mozilla (XULRunner) or WebKit (WebKitGTK+), as both can be embedded in an SWT library.

- [Mozilla XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) can be used in Windows, Linux and Mac. It can be used in SWT `Browser` class by passing `SWT.Mozilla` style flag to the constructor.
- Safary (which is WebKit) is used by SWT by default on Mac OS X. On Linux, it's default Browser [as of SWT 3.7](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserwebkitgtk) (which is just in early stages). You can force SWT use WebKit by passing system property `org.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK` as true if you have SWT 3.6.0+. On Windows, there is a port of WebKitGTK+ by GenuiTec which can be [found here](http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs-webkit-for-swt/WebKit%20For%20SWT%20Developer%20Guide.html).

To conclude, XULRunner's SVG engine is easier to work as it's support is wider. You can create an all-in-one package of your application (bundling XULRunner) for any platform. I personally do not recommend Genuitec's SWT WebKit on Windows, since it's not mature enough.